# initializing a 2D array from a file of string

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array

This is my first time working with 2D arrays. I am have read a 4 lines of strings from a text file and extracted them character by character. I am having trouble initialing an array with those characters Ive extracted. I keep getting memory locations when I try to print my array, so Im assuming the array isn't initialized properly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

public class acsiiArt 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
File file = new File("test.txt");
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

while (inputFile.hasNext())
{
    inputFile.nextInt(); 
    while (inputFile.hasNext())
    {
        inputFile.nextInt();
    while (inputFile.hasNext())
    {   
        char array [][]= new char[4][4];
        String letters = inputFile.nextLine(); 
        for(int i =0; i < letters.length(); i++)
        {
        char results = letters.charAt(i);
        for (int row = 0; row < 4;row ++)
        {
            array[row] = new char[row+1];
            for (int col =0; col< row+1; col++)
                array[row][col]= results; 
            System.out.println(array);
        }

        }    
    }   
    }
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing the `Object#toSting` representation output of the 2D `array`. In this case it would probably be simpler to iterate through the file using `nextLine` then using [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) and  [`toCharArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) to create the array.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first two integers at the beginning of the file tell the dimensions, right? Wrote this from top of my head so maybe it doesn't compile but should give you an idea:

```
public class ACSIIArt {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("test.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    int x = inputFile.nextInt();
    int y = inputFile.nextInt(); 

    char [][] letters = new char[x][y]; 
    int currentLine = 0;
    String line = null;
    while((line = inputFile.nextLine()) != null) {
        for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
             letters[currentLine][i] = line.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
             System.out.print(letters[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.print(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
 }
```

This is the basic way. There are more fancy ways to do this, such as `line.toCharArray();` but I think it is important you understand the basics first.